# Add variable to e.parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

Another simple task that google script will not do easily.

I have the following code

```
for(var i = 0; i <= cnt; ++i) {

   var type = e.parameter.type_+i;
}
```

A simple for loop, that loops through to grab the values of different post values. I have multiple inputs being sent to the script with the same name type but different numbers at the end. ie type_0, type_1. The problem is I cannot get the write combination to do this same thing through a for loop in google script.

Any ideas to get this to work right?

Comment: Thats invalid javascript

Comment: You are trying to concatenate a string, you must tell the code that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but try bracket notation instead of dot notation.

```
var t = "type_" + i;
var type = e['parameter'][t];
```

Comment: e.parameter['type_' + t];

Comment: `e.parameter['type_'+i]` actually

Comment: Worked like a charm you are a life saver